# Перевод binary to string

Tags: c#

Получилось перевести текст в binary, но обратно не получается.

Перевод в двоичный:

```
 public string StringToBinary(string data)
            {
              StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

              foreach (char c in data.ToCharArray())
                {
                    sb.Append(Convert.ToString(c, 2));
                }
                return sb.ToString();
            }
```

Обратно делаю так:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (char c in cent.ToCharArray())
        {
            sb.Append(Convert.ToString(c, 8));
        }
        return sb.ToString();
```

Во 2ом случае, выводится следущее:

> 616060616160616...

пару сотен строк, состоящие из этого.

Comment: это `StringToBinary` получает строковое представление бинарных данных - это точно то, что вам надо? Есть же методы для перевода `string->byte[]` и обратно - `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);` и `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);` (если у вас кодировка utf8)

Comment: @tym32167, попробую переписать, используя - string->byte[] и Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data); Спасибо

Comment: @tym32167, попробовал и получил не тот результат. Я, наверное, неправильно вас понял. Мне нужно получить двоичный код из строки. Например, "hello" => "010101". Я это реализовал в 1 , но не получается обратно вернуть.

Comment: Вся информация в компьютере хранится в двоичном коде. Двоичный код - это то, как представлена информация. Вот это `"010101"` - это не двоичный код, это строка из символов единиц и нулей. Вам наверное стоит объяснить, что вы делаете и для чего, иначе не понять, что вам именно надо.

Comment: Я хочу написать переводчик, который будет преобразовывать слова в код. Допустим, я ввожу букву "P", а в таблице ASCII - это 0101000, тогда мой "переводчик" выводит мне эту строку, состоящую из 0 и 1. Если честно, я в растерянности, т.к считал, что "100101" - это двоичный код и в памяти только он. @tym32167

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, то вам нужно перевести ваш текст в двоечную строку, и потом и саму двоечную строку назад в текст. Для перевода текста в двоечный вид нужно знать кодировку вашего текста (UTF8 хватает в большинстве случаев) и перевести текст в массив байтов с нужной кодировкой методом `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.ToBytes(myString);`. После чего каждый байт необходимо перевести в двоечную строку:

```
public static string ToBinaryString(byte[] data)
{
     return string.Join("", data.Select(byt => Convert.ToString(byt, 2).PadLeft(8, '0')));
}
```

В даном методе происходит следующеё:

1. Каждый байт перебираеться **LINQ**-запросом (`data.Select(...)`)
2. Байт конвертируеться в двоечный код (`Convery.ToString(byt, 2)`)
3. К конвертированому байту добавляеться приставка в форме нулей если двоечная строка меньше 8 символов (`().PadLeft(8, '0');`)
4. И все двоечные строки соединяються в одну методом `string.Join("", strings);`, где "" это разделитель между строками (в нашем случае он не нужен, поетому пустая строка).

Перевод из бинарной строки в обычную происходит в обратном порядке. Для начала получаем байты:

```
public static byte[] ToByteArray(string binaryString)
{
    int numOfBytes = binaryString.Length / 8;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[numOfBytes];
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfBytes; i++)
    {
        string oneBinaryByte = binaryString.Substring(8 * i, 8);
        bytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(oneBinaryByte, 2);
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

Так как в одном байте 8 битов, то в цикле берем подстроки по 8 символов и переводим в байт. Потом методом `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytesOfNewString);` переводим в строку.

Вот вам пример со всем кодом:

```
public static string ToBinaryString(byte[] data)
{
    return string.Join("", data.Select(byt => Convert.ToString(byt, 2).PadLeft(8, '0')));
}

public static byte[] ToByteArray(string binaryString)
{
    int numOfBytes = binaryString.Length / 8;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[numOfBytes];
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfBytes; i++)
    {
        string oneBinaryByte = binaryString.Substring(8 * i, 8);
        bytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(oneBinaryByte, 2);
    }
    return bytes;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string originString = "Мой супер текст!";
    Console.WriteLine($"Первоначальная строка: '{originString}'");

    byte[] bytesOfString = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(originString);
    string binaryString = ToBinaryString(bytesOfString);
    Console.WriteLine($"Двоечная строка: '{binaryString}'");

    byte[] bytesOfNewString = ToByteArray(binaryString);
    string newOriginString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytesOfNewString);
    Console.WriteLine($"Конвертированя строка из двоечной: '{newOriginString}'");

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Примеры кода взяты из ответов на отдельные тематики:

- [Конвертация строки в двоечную](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664345/string-to-binary-in-c-sharp#5664400)
- [Конвертация двоечной строки в массив байтов](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436398/convert-a-binary-string-representation-to-a-byte-array)

Comment: единственное, что хочу добавиить, при работе с большим количеством данных здесь `ToBinaryString` лучше использовать `StringBuilder` в целях производительности.

Comment: @tym32167 Я согласен из Вами, но алгоритм действий я надеюсь он понял.